# Using generics that extend a class

Tags: java, generics

I have a class like this:

```
public abstract class SomeClass<E extends AnotherClass> { 
    private E someVariable;

    public E formatVariable(){
        E formatted = someVariable.format(); //format is a method in AnotherClass, which returns AnotherClass
        return formatted;
    }
}
```

Eclipse gives me an error, it "cannot convert from AnotherClass to E"

I am confused because in the class decleration I made it so that E is AnotherClass or a subclass of it, or at least that was my understanding of it.

What's going on here, and how can I fix this error?

Comment: An `E` is an `AnotherClass`, but an `AnotherClass` is not necessarily an `E`. The result of `format` is an `AnotherClass`, but it isn't guaranteed to be an `E`.

Comment: @resueman That should be in the answers section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format()` returns `AnotherClass`, but you don't want just *any* AnotherClass — you want an `E` specifically. What if you had this?

```
public class AnotherClassRed extends AnotherClass {
    @Override
    public AnotherClass format() {
        return new AnotherClassBlack();
    }
}

public class AnotherClassBlack extends AnotherClass {
    // Note: This is *not* a subclass of AnotherClassRed
    ...
```

With that scenario, if things compiled then `formatVariable()` would return the formatted instance as AnotherClassRed, but the instance is actually an AnotherClassBlack; the result would be a ClassCastException.

It sounds like you want `format()` to return `E`, not `AnotherClass`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that makes sense. In my situation my method necessarily returns an object that is E, but that's because of other code within AnotherClass.